# I have a problem when I want to install auto py to exe it does not work

Tags: python

hi i have a problem when i do "pip install auto-py-to-exe" in cmd

its puts me:

"note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

```
  Encountered error while trying to install package.

  greenlet

  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. "

I have to do what ? please

Comment: @medium-dimensional OP is trying to install the package. And it is https://github.com/brentvollebregt/auto-py-to-exe. Not autoPy

Comment: Which python version are you running? it needs python >= 3.6